# Sending flash messages over Ajax (is using cookies good/bad practice ?)

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, cookies, flash-message

I'd like to send a flash message to show when a request finished. I'd like to put the message directly in PHP, because the logic of which flash message should in my opinion be in the PHP.

My problem is that I send Json data, for example when you `GET users/`

The JS receives:

```
[{user:"John","connected":true},{user:"Jane","connected":false},...] // =data
```

I would like to send the flash Message inside the response, but I don't want to change the Json Output (because it becomes less Developper friendly to send a custom object like `{"flash_message":"You are connected","data":data}`)

So I thought about setting some Cookies that expire in 1 minute, so I can show the flash message when the request is received.

Is this good practice ?

Comment: It looks like an app design issue. Explain the original problem please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using cookies is not the best way to go here, because cookies are intended to be persistent data storages, not to send data on a request.

Custom requests headers are much more appropriated.

In PHP you can send them like this:

```
header("X-flash-message-content: $message");
```

In JS you can retrieve them like this

```
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.open('GET', document.location, false);
req.send(null);
var headers = req.getAllResponseHeaders().toLowerCase();
console.log(headers);
```